# How can I access a value in a class which was set in another class in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have two classes, classA and classB.
 I navigated from classA to classB. 
I set a value
 `Temp = 0;` in classB.
I popped back to classA from classB.
Now, I need to access `Temp` value in classA.
how can I get that without setting the value in AppDelegate calss ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Property. Have a look at the apple [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html)

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSString *value;
}
@property(copy, readwrite) NSString *value;
@end



@implementation MyClass
@synthesize value;
@end
```

In another class that has a instance of MyClass

```
myInstanceOfMyClass.value = @"hi"; // Sets the value to 'hi'
NSString* myString = myInstanceOfMyClass.value; // Gets the value :)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, there are two ways to do this:

1. Create owner object in class B and initialize it with class A's object. When done with class B, set the value in class A's variable and then use it into class A
2. Create a property in App Delegate and assign this variable from Class B. When back to class A, use the variable from App Delegate.